# Can't find the first/non added value in my generic BinaryTree

Tags: java, binary-tree

im trying to create my own BinaryTree class and i also got a JUnit-Class which outputs the tests for the non added value and the first added value as a Nullpointer..

The Nullpointer occurs in my BinaryTree class at the while-loop, which doesnt make sense to me, as i've got the following lines of code to check it:

```
 if(key.compareTo(current.key) == 0) { 
          return current.value;
      }
      return null;
  }
```

The first added value should be checked first (at least i think)

Here is my code:

```
public class BinaryTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V>{ 
    int count = 0;
  //Please don't add any further attributes.
  private K key;
  private V value;
  private BinaryTree<K,V> left, right;
  private BinaryTree<K,V> root;
  /**
   * Constructor creates new BinaryTree instance, initially without child nodes.
   */
  // Done!!
  public BinaryTree(K key, V value){
      this.value = value;
      this.key = key;
      left = null;
      right = null;
  }

  /**
   * Stores a key-value pair in the tree.
   * If the key has already been stored, then the current value for this key
   * is replaced by the new value.
   */
  public void put(K key, V value) {
      BinaryTree<K,V> newNode = new BinaryTree<K,V>(key, value);
        if (root == null) {
          root = newNode;
          root.value = value;
          root.key = key;
          count += 1;
          return;
        }
        BinaryTree<K,V> current = root;
        BinaryTree<K,V> parent;
          while (true) {
            parent = current;
            if (key.compareTo(current.key) == -1) {
              current = current.left;
              if (current == null) {
                parent.left = newNode;
                count += 1;
                return;
              }
            } else {
              current = current.right;
              if (current == null) {
                parent.right = newNode;
                count += 1;
                return;
              }
            }


        }
      }


  /**
   * Returns the value object stored with the given key.
   * Returns null if the key is unknown.
   */
  public V get(K key) {
      BinaryTree<K,V> current = root;

      while(key.compareTo(current.key) != 0) {

          if(key.compareTo(current.key) < 0) {
            current = current.left;  
          } else if(key.compareTo(current.key) > 0) {
            current = current.right;           
          } 
      }
      if(key.compareTo(current.key) == 0) { 
          return current.value;
      }
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah exactly i got a NLP at the while loop in the get method

Comment: Let's see why is that

Comment: thats what im trying to figure out... i just cant understand why...

Comment: `root` is probably `null`. add this before the while loop: `if (root == null) { return null; }`

Comment: but it checks it at the beginning of the put method...: if (root == null) {
          root = newNode;
          root.value = value;
          root.key = key;
          count += 1;
          return;

Comment: @Bohemian not this is not the case

Comment: @RobinReinhardt the root is right

Comment: Why this question closed, it's not related to NPE!

Comment: still null pointer @Bohemian

Comment: It says duplicate @sc0der

Comment: but it got reopened

Comment: What has this to do with NLP (Natural Language Processing)? Did you mean NPE (NullPointerException)?

Comment: lol I ment NullPointer

Comment: @Robin Anywhere you are coding this `BinaryTree<K,V> current = root` you need to check that root is not null.

Comment: @Bohemian The problem when he inserts to the Node, he didn't update the left and right pointer, So when you retrieve he accesses Null node and this causing NPE

Comment: @sc0der whatever... using a debugger and stepping through the code is the way to solve this kind of error. "Learn to use a debugger" is the most valuable answer we can give, as per the duplicate.

Comment: hmm but if i check that root is not null before the loop it is still the same @Bohemian

Comment: okay ill give it a try @Bohemian

Comment: I have fixed the issue and about to write the answer, but Oops the question has been closed :D

Comment: wdym it has been closed?:o